# Xtext standalone and validation

Tags: xtext

Building a standalone program parsing a file, I used the first option of  http://www.davehofmann.de/?p=101

A validation is defined that give an error (red under line in eclipse) if text does not start with a capital letter.

The standalone parser does not give an error of an input file that does not pass the validation. How can I ask the standalone implementation also the verify the validations?

**Update 1**

The classed used to parse the grammar with `checkResource` included:

```
class XtextParser {
    @Inject
    private IParser parser;
    new() {
        var injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().
                          createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        injector.injectMembers(this)
    }
    def EObject parse(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        var result = parser.parse(reader)
        if (result.hasSyntaxErrors()) {
            throw new ParseException("Provided input contains syntax errors.")
        }
        var resource = result.getRootASTElement().eResource() 
        //resource is null
        //checkResource(resource)
        return result.getRootASTElement();
    }
    @Inject IResourceValidator resourceValidator

    def void checkResource(Resource resource) {
        val issues = resourceValidator.validate(resource, 
                                 CheckMode.ALL, CancelIndicator.NullImpl)
        for (issue : issues) {
            switch issue.severity {
                case ERROR:
                    println("ERROR: " + issue.message)
                case WARNING:
                    println("WARNING: " + issue.message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you dont call the validator it wont validate. so call it (pseudo code)

```
@Inject IResourceValidator resourceValidator

def void checkResource(Resource resource) {
    val issues = resourceValidator.validate(resource,
            CheckMode.ALL, CancelIndicator.NullImpl)
    for (issue: issues) {
        switch issue.severity {
            case ERROR:
                println("ERROR: " + issue.message)
            case WARNING:
                println("WARNING: " + issue.message)
        }
    }
}
```

since the blog you posted is very vague on how to call

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.xtext.util.CancelIndicator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.CheckMode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.IResourceValidator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue;

import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Injector injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = injector.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);
        Resource resource = rs.getResource(URI.createURI("test.mydsl"), true);
        resource.load(null);
        IResourceValidator validator = injector.getInstance(IResourceValidator.class);
        List<Issue> issues = validator.validate(resource,
                CheckMode.ALL, CancelIndicator.NullImpl);
        for (Issue issue: issues) {
            switch (issue.getSeverity()) {
                case ERROR:
                    System.out.println("ERROR: " + issue.getMessage());
                case WARNING:
                        System.out.println("WARNING: " + issue.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I convert object of type IParserResults to type Resource?

Comment: Parse result gives you root ast element gives  you eResource

Comment: The object returned by `result.getRootASTElement().eResource()` is null

Comment: the share your complete grammar, example model and code. i cannot read your mind

Comment: and yes the code you shared has no resource cause it is bad code

Comment: updated my answer with the "default" way how not to call IParser. nobody wants to call IParser directly. why do you want?

Comment: I need a jar file that accepts a file name what must he parsed according to the grammar. Currently  use the Hallo xtext example as a grammar.

Comment: Simply ask injector for IGenerator2 javaiofilesystemaccess and call the generator

Comment: What is the proper way to create an instance of IFileSystemAccess2?

Comment: Ask injector for javaiofilesystemaccess